# Шаблонный метод для контейнеров с++

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Имеется метод

```
void SortVector(vector<int>& vec, int topV, bool wozrastanie)
```

Хочу его сделать шаблонным, чтобы сортировать не только вектор, но и deque.
Пишу такой код, но это не работает.

```
template <typename T>
void SortVector(T<int>& vec, int topV, bool wozrastanie)
```

Можно ли решить проблему не переписывая один и тот же метод под каждый контейнер?

Comment: почему не `T & vec`? а еще есть std::sort

Comment: а второй аргумент для чего?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну, если очень хочется менять *только контейнер*, но при этом оставить тип элементов `int` - то используйте шаблонный аргумент шаблона:

```
template<template<class E,class Alloc=std::allocator<E>> typename Container>
void SortVector(Container<int>& vec, int topV, bool wozrastanie)
```

Answer (score 0):

Решение моей проблемы

```
template <typename T>
void SortVector(T & vec, int topV, bool wozrastanie)
```

Пример использования

```
SortVector<vector<int>>(vec, topV, 0);
```

Comment: Вы в проблеме четко ограничили тип элементов - `int`, и менять только тип контейнера (на что вы явно указали своей попыткой `T<int>& vec`)! А ваш метод сработает и для, скажем, `vector<string>`...

Comment: Да я указал тип `int`, но для решения моей задачи этого хватило. Спасибо за ваш ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Можно обратить свое внимание не то, как реализованы стандартные алгоритмы в stl (тот же самый std::sort). В чем особенность stl алгоритмов? - в одинаковых (с оговорками) интерфейсах у итераторов! У std::vector, std::list, std::deque, std::map и тд почти одинаковый интерфейс у итераторов. Как это используется в стандарте? Как мы можем это использовать?

```
template <typename IterType>
void user_func(IterType first, IterType last) //совершает какие то действия для диапазона [first, last)
{
    while (first != last)
    {
        std::cout << *first;
        ++first;
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}

//проверяем
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    std::list<double> l = { 3, 2, 1, 3 };

    user_func(v.begin(), v.end());                   //выведет 1 2 3 4
    user_func(v.begin(), v.begin() + v.size() / 2);  //выведет 1 2
    user_func(l.begin(), l.end());                   //выведет 3 2 1 3
}
```

Comment: не по теме ответ

Comment: почему? принимая в качестве аргументов итераторы можно работать с любыми контейнерами - и с вектором и с очередью

Comment: потому что вопрос не о том как написать общий алгоритм, а о том, как передать в функцию любой контейнер.  Если функция предназначена для работы со всей последовательностью, то зачем передать итераторы, если можно просто передать контейнер?

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Спасибо за замечания! Все таки я останусь при своем мнении. Я считаю, что передавать итераторы удобней (и лучше), чем заводить шаблон под контейнеры. В данном случае мы работаем не с контейнером, а с последовательностью. Мы не должны придумывать шаблон для контейнера, а должны просто описать последовательность - двумя итераторами (спасибо stl)/

Comment: Нет, не всегда удобно  передать итераторы. Такой подход для обобщенного алгоритма.  Часто , наоборот, удобно иметь отдельные функции, которые принимают контейнер и возвращают стандартный алгоритм,  когда нам нужно обработать  всю последовательность или ее конкретную часть. Вы должны сами знать что нет общих правил для всех задач...

Answer (score 0):

Если ваша функция должна обработать только стандартные контейнеры, то можно ввести ограничение, чтобы она принимала только объекты шаблонных классов, поскольку все стандартные контейнеры шаблонные. Но и лучше иметь возможность  обработать контейнер с любым типом элементов(в случаи сортировки типы элементов должны иметь свойство сравниваться).  И так, я предлагаю вариант:

```
template <typename T, template<typename> class   Cont>
void SortVector(Cont<T>& vec, int topV, bool wozrastanie)
{
    //...

}
```

Ну и вам решать для чего второй аргумент функции...